# cte in sql server with temp table and split string

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, temp-tables

I have table with two colums ID and rights. Rights column will keep 250 fixed characters in 0,1 form like '010111100000000....250 times'. Now I have to split the rights column string and get the results in temp table which will have the structure ID, Rights(0 or 1), Position(1 to 250). Suppose I have 5 rows initially then in temp table I will get 5*250 = 1250 rows.

I have split the single string and used cursor but now I want to avoid cursor. How I can achieve this.

```
declare  @temp table(Chars int not null, RowID int not null)

    --Split the rights string into 250 char rows with RowID as each position
    ;with cte as
    (
        select substring(@rights, 1, 1) as Chars,
                stuff(@rights, 1, 1, '') as rights,
                1 as RowID
        union all
        select substring(rights, 1, 1) as Chars,
                stuff(rights, 1, 1, '') as rights,
                RowID + 1 as RowID
        from cte
        where len(rights) > 0

    )

    --Get the values in a temporary table except 0
    insert into @temp select Chars, RowID from cte  option (MAXRECURSION 300);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

The idea is: Get a list of 250 running numbers and use `SUBSTRING` to read one character from each position:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY,Rights VARCHAR(250));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('1011101110000101010111000...'), ('0100010111100010101...');

WITH Nr250 AS
(SELECT TOP 250 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Nr FROM master.dbo.spt_values)

SELECT t.ID 
      ,t.Rights
      ,Nr AS Position
      ,SUBSTRING(t.Rights,Nr,1) AS PosDigit
--INTO #SomeTempTable
FROM Nr250
CROSS JOIN @tbl AS t
```

If you want to write this into a temp table, just remove the `--` before `INTO`